# How to check if Injectable Value is set in Jackson Deserializer

Tags: java, exception, serialization, jackson, injectable

I have a class that extends `JsonDerserializer<Type>`.  In this deserialiser I have a concept of doing replacement values which I currently set using objectReader(Injectables). My problem is that sometimes I don't have injectables.

I don't see a method on `ObjectMapper` that allows me to check if an injectable key is set.  I only see `findInjectableValue` which if the value isn't there it throws an `InvalidDefinitionException`. I am currently try catching this call which works, but I feel it is more of a hack.

Is there something I am missing?

I really don't want to have this `try-catch`. I want to first check if injectable value exists.

```java
try {
  Object replacementValueObject = ctxt.findInjectableValue("replacementValues", null, null);
  if (replacementValueObject instanceof Map) {
    replacementValues = (Map<String, Object>) replacementValueObject;
    mapper.setInjectableValues(new InjectableValues.Std().addValue("replacementValues", replacementValues));
  }
}catch (InvalidDefinitionException ie){
  logger.info("No replacement values exist.  Ignoring and moving on");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now (`07-2019`), there is no method to check whether value exists or not. You can only [addValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/InjectableValues.Std.html#addValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) and try to get it by invoking [findInjectableValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/InjectableValues.Std.html#findInjectableValue-java.lang.Object-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty-java.lang.Object-).

You can create empty `Map` and initialise `InjectableValues` when `ObjectMapper` is created:

```
InjectableValues.Std injectableValues = new InjectableValues.Std();
injectableValues.addValue("replacementValues", Collections.emptyMap());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setInjectableValues(injectableValues);
```

or create nice method which hides complex logic behind scene:

```
class ReplaceMapValueJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object intoValue) throws IOException {
        Map replacementValues = getCurrentReplacementValues(ctxt);
        //...

        return super.deserialize(p, ctxt, intoValue);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getCurrentReplacementValues(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        try {
            Object value = ctxt.findInjectableValue("replacementValues", null, null);
            return (Map<String, Object>) value;
        } catch (JsonMappingException ie) {
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to use injection with XmlMapper deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015253/how-to-use-injection-with-xmlmapper-deserialization)