# How to inject dependency into Jackson Custom serializer

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777586/how-to-inject-dependency-into-jackson-custom-deserializer) question I've seen an interesting approach for injecting objects into custom deserializers for the Jackson mapping framework (I'm currently on **version 2.10.x**). 
Essentially, one registers a dependency MyService in the `ObjectMapper`

```java
 jsonMapper.setInjectableValues(new InjectableValues
                .Std()
                .addValue(MyService.class.getName(), myServiceInstance));
```

and then in a class that extends `StdDeserializer` it can be accessed through the `DeserializationContext` which has a `findInjectableValue` method.

Now, I hope the library provides a symmetric approach for serialisation, but honestly could not find it. Specifically, if you have a class that extends `StdSerializer`, you will need to implement a method  `serialize(ProjectSerializable value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider)` which doesn't seems to have a class with similar features of `DeserializationContext`.

So, how can one achieve the same "injection" with a custom serializer without resorting to ugly solutions based on static access to instance providers or other untestable things.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the only way to achieve this is via setting attributes for the `SerializerProvider` that will be used by the custom serializer.

When you create the `ObjectMapper`, then you have to hack it by creating a new one

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = ...// here you create the ObjectMapper will all your configs

// Then you inject the service.

SerializationConfig initialSerializationConfig = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig();
ContextAttributes attributes = initialSerializationConfig.getAttributes();
// Here we create a new ContextAttributes with the class we want 
//   to have shared for each serializer
ContextAttributes attributesWithInjectedValue =
         attributes.withSharedAttribute(MyService.class.getName(), myServiceInstance);
SerializationConfig serializationConfigWithInjectedValue =
         initialSerializationConfig.with(attributesWithInjectedValue);

return jsonMapper.setConfig(serializationConfigWithInjectedValue);
```

Then in the instance of the `JsonSerializer` you simply do:

```java
MyService myService = (MyService) serializerProvider
        .getAttribute(MyService.class.getName());
```

where `serializerProvider` is the instance of `SerializerProvider` given with the `serialize` method.

I don't like the asymmetry with the other approach shown for deserialization, but it works.